# Como logear usuario en WebForms de manera Remota C#, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola tengo una duda acerca de inicio de sesión en web forms, mi inicio de sesión funciona a la perfección de esta manera:

Login.aspx:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al hacer click, llama a una clase que valida y devuelve true o false, de acuerdo a las credenciales enviadas y consultadas en la base de datos "Usuarios" 
Login.cs:

```js
 protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        bool Autenticado = false;
        cls_login validacion = new cls_login();
        Autenticado = validacion.validar(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);
        if (Autenticado) {

            e.Authenticated = Autenticado;
        }
        
       
    }
```

El problema es que estoy haciendo una extensión para Chrome, donde al abrirse el Popup es iframe a la pagina web de mi aplicación WebForms, donde obviamente se abre la pagina de inició de sesión, donde se logean y todo funciona a la perfección.

Lo molesto es que me gustaría que cada vez que abrieran la extensión evitaran el tener que logearse.

No me gustaría que la aplicación webforms la sesión nunca caduque, si no más bien mi solución era que en las opciones de mi extensión guardara el usuario y contraseña y mediante **javascript ajax**, llamara  a un **WebHandler** donde este recibe las credenciales e iniciara sesión, pero no logro hacerlo ya que no tengo los mismos eventos como en mi login.cs :

```js
   protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
```

Hasta la fecha he podido llamar a mi  **WebHandler** mediante JS (desde la extensión de chrome), ha recibido los parámetros correctamente, ha llamado a mi clase de validación que esta a su vez consulta la base de datos en SQL, y el Handler devuelve true o false, que igual manera funciona correctamente.

Mi duda es como puedo generar un "login" en una clase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya lo pude solucionar, un login no se puede crear en una clase en App_Code, así que cree un WebMethod que recibe usuario y contraseña desde un html con javascript (ajax)

El código es el siguiente:

```js
public partial class service_login_text : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string setLogin(string usuario, string password)
    {
        if (usuario != null && password != null) { //Comprobamos que los datos recibidos desde ajax no sean nulos
            try {
                bool login = false; // Establecemos login en falso hasta que se demeustre lo contrario
                cls_login validacion = new cls_login(); // Instanciamos nuestra clase que validara el login en una BD
                login = validacion.validar(usuario, password); // Llamanos a nuestra función y esta devolvera un true o false

                if (login) { // Si fue correcto creamos la autentificación
                    service_login_text autentificacion = new service_login_text(); // Creamos nuestra instancia de esta misma clase
                    object sender = new object(); // Objeto generico
                    autentificacion.Login1_Authenticate(sender, new AuthenticateEventArgs(), usuario); // Parametros de envio
                    return "Login correcto";
                }
                else { return "Login Incorrecto"; };
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {

                return "Error Catch";
            }
        } else{   
            return "No se ha recibido información";
        }
    }

    // La clase de autentificación esta en en el mismo WebMethod por que permite crear las variables "Session" lo cual es imposible crear
    // en una clase ubicada en App_Code por que el nivel de protección no lo permite.
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e, string usuario){
        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = usuario; //El truco esta en crear la variable "UserName" con un usuario válido y "IsAuthenticated" en true
        HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAuthenticated"] = true;

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usuario, true); // Creamos una cookie de autentificación
        e.Authenticated = true; // El evento  AuthenticateEventArgs en true
    }
}
```

Comment: Si tu mismo encontraste la respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Hola buen día, busque y no encuentro la manera de marcarla como solucionada, hay alguna función en especial o tengo que editar el mismo titulo?

Comment: Simplemente marca el check que aparece debajo de las flechas de las respuesta. Cuando se vuelva verde quiere decir que la respuesta ha sido aceptada

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, primera vez y primer día que uso Stack, saludos desde México.